# javascript: call a default function?

Tags: javascript, function, call, default

I need to make some js functionality like that:

```
let text =function()
{
    this.main = ...;
    this.toArr = ...;
};

let t = new text();

console.log( t() ); // call a function 'main' in text;
t().toArr(); // call a function 'toArr' in text;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not really clear what you're asking. We can help you literally do what you describe, but it's unusual and probably not quite what you really *want* to do.

Comment: You need to ask a clear and concise question.  Along w/this you need to explain exactly what you did to solve it and the problems you're having.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a *very active place*. When you post a question (or an answer), *stick around for a while* to address any issues raised by commenters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let text = function (myarg) {
    // Usage: var t = new text(<arg>);
    this.uniqueProperty = "test";
    var main = () => {
        // main code
        return {
            toArr: () => {
                return [myarg, this.uniqueProperty];
            }
        };
    };
    return main;
}

var t = new text("hey world");

console.log(t());
console.log(t().toArr());
```

Calls are the same as in your question

**Note:** your main function returns object now.

---

## How does this work?

You call `new text("arg")`, but constructor returns main function instead of `this`. Main function returns object with `toArr` function, and can be accessed through `new text("arg")().toArr` code. Why I put both functions into `() => {}`?. The answer is simple - that's how to access text instance properties. So we can access unique `text` properties. Else, `this` will be `main` function reference.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a deeply look at [MDN's Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) part.

This is a simple usage as below:

```js
let text = function()
{
    this.main = function(){
      return {a:1};
    }
    this.toArr = function(){
      return [1,2,3];
    }
};

let t = new text();

console.log( t.main() ); // call a function 'main' in text;
console.log(t.toArr()); // call a function 'toArr' in text;
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what he wants. He want to call main function with `t()` code, not with `t.main()`. Check my answer.